# Goodness of fit with parameter estimation for non-normal distributions

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit

I am looking for library in R which can test a vector for different parametrized distributions together with parameters estimation, which returns Anderson-Darling statistics and p-value.

Let’s say we have a vector:

```
x <- c(0.061, 0.063, 0.082, 0.059, 0.051, 0.081, 0.052, 0.063, 0.083,
0.066, 0.079, 0.054, 0.072, 0.069, 0.062, 0.058, 0.07, 0.057, 0.063, 0.083,
0.059, 0.052, 0.065, 0.071, 0.06, 0.073, 0.064, 0.089, 0.068, 0.052)
```

For normal distribution I can use `ad.test` from `nortest` library:

```
>nortest::ad.test(x)

        Anderson-Darling normality test

data:  x
A = 0.51814, p-value = 0.1735
```

But I can’t find a tool that does the same for other parametrized distributions like lognormal, weibull, gamma etc. I thought that I can do it with `goftest` library, but it requires that distribution parameters are known, so mean and standard deviation are specified, not estimated:

```
> goftest::ad.test(x, 'pnorm', mean(x), sd(x))

    Anderson-Darling test of goodness-of-fit
    Null hypothesis: Normal distribution

data:  x
An = 0.51814, p-value = 0.727
```

P-value in `ad.test` from `goftest` library is higher, because this funcion tests normality with assumption of known mean and standard deviation. (I also do not understand why p-values are different and A-D results are the same in both cases).

With other distributions p-values are higher too, for example:

```
> goftest::ad.test(x, 'plnorm', mean(log(x)), sd(log(x)))
An = 0.33688, p-value = 0.9074
```

So if I was going to test for normality only, it would be sufficient to use `nortest` library. But I also need to test for other distributions.

Concluding, I am looking for a solution that tests goodness of fit for different distributions, calculates A-D statistic and p-value, and estimates distribution parameters by itself (like `nortest::ad.test` does for normal distribution).

Bellow you can see correct results generated in Minitab, which I want to reproduce in R. As you can see p-values are lower than in `goftest::ad.test` (but equal to result from `nortest::ad.test` in case of normal distribution).

```
Goodness of Fit Test

    Distribution     AD       P
    Normal        0,518   0,174
    Lognormal     0,337   0,482
    Weibull       0,769   0,042
    Gamma         0,405  >0,250
```

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: To find the best fitting parametrized distribution for a dataset.

Comment: which is a futile exercise since their is an infinite number of distributions. There is rarely a good reason for a purely data-driven approach to finding a distribution model.

Comment: You are right, but one of my goals is to reproduce results from Individual Distribution Identification method from Minitab. So I need to try to fit the data to a few most expected models only.